# Removing Zero from input type number - Angular 7

Tags: html, angular

My question is about default value, I tried to remove the zero when the page loads but nothing turned to be working, so do you guys have any ideas?

```
<ui-input
id="cost-input"
[labelText]="'Enter the Price:'"
[type]="'number'"
[(inputModel)]="clothing.clothingCost"
[placeholder]="''"
(inputModelChange)="checkSubmit()"
></ui-input>
```

Comment: You need to do a better effort on the question, explain better what you are doing, and write more code for your example. Remember that people here what to help, but non will spend time trying to guess your problem.

Comment: you can setup so that `clothing.clothingCost` is `null` on init then it will change based on selection.